# Run Mongo command daily

Tags: mongodb

I need to update some documents in mongodb every day at `6:00 AM`.

For example, daily at `6:00 AM`, I want to execute this command: `db.foo.remove()`.

How can I do that? Can this be done by just using Mongo shell?

If not, what should I use?

Comment: What platform do you use: Linux, Windows, other?

Comment: @イオニカ ビザウ Thanks to edit, and i use linux ubuntu

Comment: If you want to schedule a task to run in MongoDB, the best way to do this is with the operating system scheduler.  For example, 'cron' on Unix/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare batch script, and from windows task manager you can run that script every day on given time